# copSSH prevent user from going back into copSSH directory

Tags: windows, security, ssh, sftp

I have installed SFTP on a windows servers using copSSH and all is good and it works well
however you can go back from the main root.

For example when i use C:\copSSH\home{username} as that user i can go back into copSSH and into them directories too.

And I have a user setup to actually be C:\inetpub\wwwroot but that user can go into the system and everything i have this set as my path /cygdrive/c/inetpub/wwwroot

It would be ideal if the user could only go forward from the start directory, rather than out and about there is no write ability but there is read and download....... now for the tags ????

Comment: Not programming-related - belongs on superuser/serverfault ?

Comment: oh bummer im so used to using this site

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the user only has access to "home{username}" folder, and does not have any access to other folders.